# How to change the template from jade to html in angular meanstack project

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

When I was creating project using Yo angular fullstack, I was selected jade is template engin. But I want to change it to html. And I want change all jade file to html file. It is possible and How can, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've finished generating the project through Yeoman there's no way to automatically switch everything back to html. You'll have to either create a new project from scratch with new settings or edit your current project's config files (Grunt, Karma, etc.) to no longer process the .jade files. Of course, you'll have to redo all of the Jade templates into HTML.

Personally, I would create a new project with HTML selected and, then, copy and paste any files from my old project that I needed to keep into my new project.